# Angular js watch session Storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, session-storage, web-storage

I have some data from different controllers that are stored in the sessionStorga using https://github.com/fredricrylander/angular-webstorage. The data is stored ok and it's available in the current session.
The problem I am facing regards making a controller that will watch for changes in the webstorage.session I did this like this:

```
app.controller(
    'updateDataController',
    ['$scope','$http','$sce','$location','$routeParams', '$rootScope', '$document', 'webStorage', '$interval', 'md5',
        function($scope,$http,$sce,$location,$routeParams, $rootScope, $document, webStorage, $interval, md5) {

            $scope.mySessionStorage = webStorage.session;

            $scope.$watch('mySessionStorage', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                 console.log("The web storage has changed");
            }, true);

        }
    ]);
```

I get the console.log output only once. I don't get any logs even though I change the content of webStorage.session. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`webStorage.session` is only setting the value to `$scope.mySessionStorage` one time upon the initialization of your controller.  So that code above the watch is only firing one time.

Try watching the `webStorage.session` value instead of the value in the controller:

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
   return webStorage.session;
}, function (newVal, oldVal) {
   console.log("The web storage has changed");
}, true);
```

Comment: It doesn't work like this but if I replace webStorage.session with sessionStorage it works... don't really know why...

Comment: @exilonX is right. also we can set watch on specific key by returning sessionStorage.getItem("<KEY>") instead of just sessionStorage.